# Centos7, firewall-cmd --reload, "COMMAND_FAILED --state requires an argument" How to give state an argument?

Tags: ssh, iptables, centos7, firewall-cmd

I am using Centos7 and have just made some changes to the firewall. I am trying to configure my firewall to filter my ssh connection. I am following the How To documentation on [Centos7 How Tos, Securing OpenSSh: Filter SSH at the Firewall.](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#head-a296ec93e31637aa349538be07b37f67d836688a) Essentially these fire wall settings are recording access to port 22, and limiting the number of times the ip can access the port to 4 times in 60 seconds. These are the commands I have just ran.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name ssh --rsource
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent ! --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --name ssh --rsource -j ACCEPT 

firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 4 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
firewall-cmd --reload
```

On firewall-cmd --reload I recive an the error

```
Error: COMMAND_FAILED: Direct: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.4.21: option "--state" requires an argument
Error occured at line: 2
Try 'iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more infomation.
```

Not sure what to do next.
How do i give state an argument?

Comment: Why not just use one or the other? If you're going to use `firewalld` then you don't need `iptables`.

Comment: Is your system up to date? Why have you entered manual iptables commands?